# How to hide dropdownbox data with specific list Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

So I have a `Dropdown Box` which contains data 'Dog', 'Lion', and 'Cat' so once I select the Dog it will not show in the Dropdown List how to achieve that, is it possible?

HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field class="full-width" floatLabel="always" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Choose Animal</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="animal">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let items of animal" [value]="items.id">
      {{items.animal}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```js
ngOninit() {
  this.getList()
}

getList() {
  this.animalSVC.getListOfAnimal().subscribe((response: AnimalDTO) => {
    this.animalObj = response;
    this.animalDS = this.animalObj.items
  })
}
```

For example, I select the lion in the list once I selected it will not show in the selected box again

Comment: Please include more relevant code. What the data looks like you get from the response? Otherwise the code looks fine, must be a bug in some part of the code we don't see. Example: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-hint-error-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is not select multiple, you can use

```
  <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods"
    [hidden]="food.value==form.get('food')?.value"
    [value]="food.value"
  >
    {{food.viewValue}}
  </mat-option>
```

And add the .css

```
  mat-option[hidden]{
    display:none
  }
```

But if is multiple, we should give to the user an oportunity to "unselect"

For this we create a variable that change, when open/close the mat-select and when an option is unselected

```
  oldValue:any[]=[]

  <mat-select formControlName="foodMultiple" multiple 
     (openedChange)="oldValue=form.get('foodMultiple')?.value||[]"
     >
    <mat-option #option *ngFor="let food of foods"
      (onSelectionChange)="!option.selected && unSelect(option.value)"
      [hidden]="(form.get('foodMultiple')?.value||[]).indexOf(food.value)>=0 
                && oldValue.indexOf(food.value)<0"
      [value]="food.value"
    >
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

See that we use a template reference variable (the `#option`) that allow us know if is or not selected `option.selected` and pass to the function unSelect the value `option.value`

The construction `(event)="condition && function()"`, makes that if the condition is not fullfilled, the function is not executed

```
  unSelect(value:string)
  {
      this.oldValue=this.oldValue.filter(x=>x!=value)
  }
```

So, if we unselect the next time we select it's remove.

NOTE: We can also not check if an option is deselected and don't change the oldValue variable, but them this not desapear if is checked again

NOTE2: I use the "classic" `[hidden]` that you use normally in a typical select tag. It's the same if we use a class in the way `[class.nodisplay]=...` and the .css `mat-option.nodisplay`

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-poyscq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable like `animalSelectedId: number = null` in global first.
Then, create a on changes function to store the animal you selected. When you for loop the animal array, only show the animal item which is not the same as `animalSelectedId`.

```html
 <mat-form-field class="full-width" floatLabel="always" appearance="outline">
   <mat-label>Choose Animal</mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="animal" (selectionChange)="onChange($event)">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let items of animal" [value]="items.id">
            <div *ngIf="items.id !== animalSelectedId">
              {{items.animal}}
            </div>
         </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

```js
animalSelectedId: number = null

public onChange(e: {value: number}): void {
  animalSelectedId = e.value;
}
```

Comment: i have multiple dropdown i tried you code but it wont show once i selected it

Comment: It's better to show your code on CodeSandBox

Comment: @馬料水碼農, you can use directly `<div *ngIf="items.id!==form.get('animal).value">` and you needn't an auxiliar variable nor onChange function